# "Вызвал" или "вызвало"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

«Первое лицо аэропорта» вызвал наряд полиции..

Comment: Наряд вызвал лицо или лицо вызвало наряд?

Comment: Начальник аэропорта вызвал наряд полиции...

Comment: Составителям рапорта известен пол лица?

Comment: Мужской пол у лица.

Comment: У меня больше вопросов вызывает "первое лицо аэропорта"?  Это кто? Если директор, то лучше так и писать.

Comment: Скорее, вождь: действие происходит на оч. маленьком острове.

Comment: На острове это точно мужчина. И вообще, к чему эти подробности, для читателя они непринципиальны. "Первое лицо аэропорта"  (вместо директора) - стилистический прием в художественном тексте, немного ироничный. Так что всё на месте.

Answer (score 1):

**«Первое лицо аэропорта» вызвал наряд полиции...**

Розенталь [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_06](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_06)

7. При подлежащем – прозвище лица сказуемое принимает **форму рода, которая соответствует полу называемого лица**, например: В августе Редька приказал нам собираться на линию (Чехов); Из-за суконной занавески появилась «Великий Могол» с подносом (А.Н. Толстой) (речь идет о горничной Луше).

Answer (score 0):

Можно было бы сомневаться, если бы не было кавычек, но в данном случае нет сомнений: глагол должен соответствовать роду упомянутого чиновника (вызвал или вызвала). А если род неизвестен, то лучше так не писать.